# what browsers should I support, and how would you do it on a mac?

Tags: cross-browser

I'm using a lot of HTML5/CSS3 and am on a mac. Everything looks great for me, but I'm not my customer :(.

If you were looking to set something up for the best cross browser testing,

1) What browsers would you support?

2) What would be the best thing to do, if you were on a mac?

Comment: I use browserstack.com to test on different operating systems and browsers.

Comment: "what browsers should I support" - FF, Chrome, Safari, and Opera if you're pedantic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is a not specific and open ended question, I'd try to identify the browsers that most of my users use. For example, if my application is targeted to banks and huge corporations, I'd definitely want to include ie 7 into targeted browsers. Otherwise, I think it's not worthed the effort to make the site ie7 compatible.

A few guidelines:

- use [Bootstrap from twitter](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)
- use [HTML5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)
- use [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)

You can test how your site looks on other browsers by having VMs running on your mac

Answer (score 0):

1) Most popular browsers, i.e.: IE (>=8), FF, Chrome, Safari, probably Opera
2) Maybe setup some windows virtual machine with help of (VirtualBox or VMWare fusion) to test IE